# python-IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe at self.subp_.stdin.flush()

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

```
def send( self, sendStr, detailedTrace=False ):
    trace = t4 if detailedTrace else t1
    trace( self.tag_, 'send: %r' %( sendStr ))
    self.subp_.stdin.write( sendStr )
    self.subp_.stdin.flush()
```

## [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Please help as I am getting broken pipe issue at self.subp_.stdin.flush()

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xxx/xyz.py", line 239, in send
  >     self.subp_.stdin.flush()
  > IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe